# How do I find a directory when I'm connected through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, find

I am inside the home directory of a Linux machine (which I logged into using Putty).

From there on I need to find a folder named `my-web1.0`.

Is there any way to go know the path of that directory named my-web1.0?

Comment: `locate` can be handy and fast if you are running `updatedb` already

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `find` command:

```
find $HOME -name my-web1.0 -type d -print
```

If that doesn't produce any results, the folder is probably somewhere else. Try `/` instead of `$HOME` but that might take some time (searches the whole disk).

**[EDIT]** That will print the path. Use `cd "path"` to go there. The quotes are only necessary when the path contains spaces.

Comment: And if you use `/` as path, append a `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command.

Comment: Do notice the original question also asked "how to **go to** the path", this answer merely replies how to find the path.

Answer (score 1):

if my-web1.0 is within your home folder:

```
cd ~
find . -type d -name 'my-web1.0'
```

if you don't know where it is at all:

```
find / -type d -name 'my-web1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tree view

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

then

```
tree -L 1
```

or just use

```
tree
```

You can obtain more information about it using

```
man tree
```